# How to merge Lot/Serial number

Tags: view, odoo, wizard, odoo-12

I want to add a wizard with `Many2many` field of `'stock.production.lot'` displaying only the records with doubled `Lot/Serial Number`
i did the function that get the filtred records ,now i need to display it

```
class DoublingNumber(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'doubling.number'
    

    double_number_id =fields.Many2many('stock.production.lot' ,string="Numéros en doublant" )

     @api.multi
        def _default_double_number(self):
            log.warning("Hola")
            double_record = []
            records =self.env['stock.production.lot'].search([])
            for record in records :
                for record2 in records :
                    if record.name == record2.name and record.product_id != record2.product_id :
    
                        double_record.append(record2)    
                         
                        break
            return double_record
```

Now how to display it ??!

Comment: You can use the default keyword to specify the function that computes the value of ``double_number_id`` field and return a record set. You can find an example in [calendar](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/calendar/models/calendar.py#L867) module, the function is defined at line [585](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/b60e1574ede3cf2944d2dfb4bbff9af2f5058841/addons/calendar/models/calendar.py#L585)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the default function within the field definition, but define the function before the field and define it in the following way instead :

```
class DoublingNumber(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'doubling.number'

    @api.model
    def _default_double_number(self):
        log.warning("Hola")
        double_record = self.env['stock.production.lot']
        records =self.env['stock.production.lot'].search([])
        for record in records :
            for record2 in records :
                if record.name == record2.name and record.product_id != record2.product_id :

                    double_record += record2  
                     
                    break
        return double_record
    
    double_number_id =fields.Many2many('stock.production.lot' ,string="Numéros en doublant", default = _default_double_number)
```

Good luck :)